# Agressive -O2 optimization by clang

Tags: c++, macos, casting, clang, compiler-optimization

I have a problem of different results produced by a simple C++ code compiled on macOS 11 with

clang version 14.0.6
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0

The program is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
template<typename T, typename U, typename O> inline static void add(T* l, size_t size, U r, O* o)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size ; ++i)
    {
        o[i] = (O)l[i] + (O)r;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double x[4] = {-1,-1,-1,-1};
    unsigned char y = 127;
    unsigned char z[4];
    
    add(x, 4, y, z);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("z[%zu]=%u\n",i,z[i]);
    }
}
```

and the to different results are (with and without `-O2` optimization):

```
$ clang -O2 add.cpp -o add; ./add
z[0]=0
z[1]=0
z[2]=0
z[3]=0

$ clang add.cpp -o add; ./add
z[0]=126
z[1]=126
z[2]=126
z[3]=126
```

correct result is the one without optimization. How can I have the correct results when using optimization ?

Comment: Such thing is usually indication of Undefined Behavior in a code.

Comment: does it actually matter whether `add` is a template? If not you could make it a plain function

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking about it, but what would be undefined behavior here besides casting operations or eventual integer overflow ?

Comment: Clang with `-fsanitize=undefined` even tells you what it does not like about it: https://godbolt.org/z/jKMqKdcv6

Comment: Here is repro https://godbolt.org/z/dE7vr7o7z

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet The UB would be the cast of -1.0 to unsigned char, since it cannot be represented by the destination type. "If the value cannot fit into the destination type, the behavior is undefined (even when the destination type is unsigned, modulo arithmetic does not apply)."

Comment: If you do `static_cast<O>(static_cast<int>(l[i]))` there will be no UB, since cast to `int` is fine then casting to unsigned value is well defined since it is done modulo 2^numberOfBits. https://godbolt.org/z/re5EG9s6c

Comment: Here someone made nice list of UBs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a/367662#367662

Comment: Which ones of the two casts, both ?

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet The one that actually does something (i.e. `(O)l[i]` -- `r` is already an `unsigned char`, so that's basically a noop).